# Run Time Error 1004 You Can't Paste This Here

Tags: excel, vba

My code worked for the first 800 iterations (it's running through a folder with about 4,000 files), and now it's throwing this error

> "Run-time error '1004': You can't paste this here because the Copy
>   area and paste area aren't the same size. Select just one cell in the
>   paste area or an area that's the same size, and try pasting again."

This is my code: (only the part relevant to the error)

```
With sht1
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            With .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count)
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Columns(1))) Then
                    .Cells.Copy Destination:=.Cells(.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
                End If
                .AutoFilter
                .Cells(1, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count, 1).EntireRow.Delete
            End With
        End With
    End With
```

The error occurs on this line:

```
.Cells.Copy Destination:=.Cells(.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
```

Comment: "the first 800 iterations"!? Perhaps you've gone off the bottom of the sheet?

Comment: @SJR the code runs through a folder with about 4k files. It runs this piece on each file once, then saves and closes. I don't mean 800 iterations on a single file/sheet.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint and stepping through to see what happens when it errors?

Comment: @SJR yes. I've stepped through the code. I don't see why it's happening though, because since it's pasting to an area below the current data it has as much space as it needs, and the data always starts in the same place and finishes with the same number of columns.

Comment: Try debug.print or a msgbox on `currentregion.address` before you copy to check it's expected.

Comment: @SJR thanks for that tip. I checked and it's definitely picking up on the correct cells to copy and paste.

Comment: Would the number of rows matter? Each files has more data than the one before, so before I was pasting into row 600k, I'm now pasting into row 900k.

Comment: Only if you run the risk of going over the end  of the sheet as per original comment.

Comment: @SJR What does that mean? Doesn't excel give me as many cells as I need to, to work with?

Comment: I ran a test by deleting a few thousand rows, and the paste worked. Looks like excel doesn't allow me to have that much data in a sheet. Any workarounds for this (other than creating a second tab and copying to that?

Comment: That's too broad a question I think. The whole set-up sounds very resource-intensive and am surprised it's not incredibly slow. Excel may not be the best tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue is that excel only allows a maximum of 1,048,576 rows, and I was trying to paste below that.

To work around the limitations and to speed up my code, I now use PowerQuery to import and filter the data down.